# how to change woocommerce quantity field value from gravity forms field?

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I've tried changing the value of the woocommerce quantity field from another field using gravityforms plugin  with number field and calculations form, but didn't work. How to do it? Please help

Answer (score 1):

In the Woocommerce product, if you have the WooCommerce Gravity Forms Product Add-Ons plugin activated, you can select the form you want to use, then in the Form Display at the bottom, you'll see advanced options. For Replace Modified Items? select Yes, for Quantity and Stock, select Yes, and then choose the field you want to populate the cart's quantity.

The advanced options will look for a number or quantity field to replace the woocommerce product quantity.